# How to Set PTR Record?

Tags: godaddy, google-compute-engine, cloudflare

I have a domain from **Godaddy**, its application runs at **Google Compute Engine** and is traffic controlled by **Cloudflare**.

For sometime now we have observed decrease in our mails deliverability to users inbox. One of the method to resolve the issue is to add PTR Record.

Could you please help me with how and where to add PTR Record?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "teach me how to cimputer" is not what we do here.

Answer (score 5):

The `PTR` record (also called `reverse DNS record`) is not located in the domain's zone but in the ARPA's zone, as it relates to the IP address, not the domain name.

That record needs to be created by your SMTP server's ISP for its static IP address.

That is not something done through Cloudflare, which would be impossible since the IP addresses they use are shared ([as described on their site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168596-How-do-I-add-a-PTR-record-to-CloudFlare-)).

Comment: how can i add PTR record?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal - as stated by Julie, you need to ask your ISP to create it for you

Comment: And when you do, make sure that you ask them for a TTL of _at least_ 24 hours or you will _not_ get off some blacklists

Comment: @Colt:  I doubt that could be an issue as any provider that gives static IPs deals with this an a daily basis.

Comment: Believe it or not, I recently had to get in a big argument with one on a static /29

Answer (score 2):

If your mail domain points to the GCE server's IP address, there is currently no way to add a PTR (reverse DNS), as this feature is not yet implemented by Google. It has been [requested by many users](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=51).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up ptr record was answerd in Julie Pelletiers post (you should contact ISP who owns IP you're sending mail from).

Your problem might not be with ptr at all.

First you should know where you're sending email from. Your Google Compute Engine Server? From email server in your office? Are you using a third party's email service? In first two cases, you should have PTR (reverse) record set for IP you're sending email from and value should be hostname of your server. In third case, that company should have PTR and delivery problem might be related to it's reputation or missing/bad spf/dkim records.

Collect more information about your email settings and mail delivery reports (bounced emails and email server delivery logs should provide necessary data) and update your post.

Answer (score -3):

Login to GoDaddy and Select domain, go to Manage DNS and Modify DNS there you will have option to Add PTR record.

If you have modified domain name server then you won't be able to add any DNS record under your godaddy account. Find the option to add DNS record either PTR or Reserve DNS under your hosting account.